# Reuse UI (xib files)

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch

In my app I have two screens - first to show a user profile, the second - to edit the profile information. They are similar. I have completed the  xib file for the first screen.

What's the best way to reuse it on second screen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should encapsulate the related elements as a custom view class. You can tackle this problem by creating views with code instead of just xibs, and I would recommend this.

But, if you would prefer to use a xib, you can create one that models the stuff you want to reuse. And then in your view controller call some code like this:

```
UIView* aView = [UIView alloc] initWithFrame .....];
[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyReusableComponent" owner:aView options:nil];
UILabel* someLabel = aView.injectedLabel; //this is alive after loading the xib
[self.view addSubView:aView];
```

When you create your xib, your need to set the Files Owner to a class that will respond to the setters for the properties that will be injected. (Eg your new view class). This way you can wire up the references.

For more information, look at Apple's examples of loading table cells from a xib - this is the same technique. When you load a xib and specify the owner, it will inject the values from the xib into the owner, in this case a custom view.

[image]

Comment: +1 for code rather than nibs; I've never found a case where nibs did more good than harm in the long or even medium term.

Comment: nibs are very useful, especially on the long run, but you have to know where to stop and how to divide the UI between them correctly.

Comment: @valentin - you are right, they can certainly be done properly if this is your preference. .

Comment: @simon They're great for learning. Once things get more complex, I prefer code. I was dazzled first time I saw them tho!

Comment: @user404201 honestly, I don't even think they're good for learning. All they do is delay the point at which you learn to do it properly, and build up problems without teaching you how to solve them.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `UITextField`s (instead of `UILabel`s you may have logically used for show) that you change in appearance, and switch `enabled` on/off.  As a minimal example:

**Show**:

```
self.textField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleNone;
self.textfield.enabled     = NO;
```

**Edit**:

```
self.textField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleBezel;
self.textfield.enabled     = YES;
```

You could of course do more on appearance, than just these basics.

Answer (score 0):

Dou you mean that you enter the view controller's edit mode and reuse  those those elements you have created ?

[Enabling Edit Mode in a View Controller](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/EnablingEditModeinaViewController/EnablingEditModeinaViewController.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH14-SW1)

Answer (score -1):

In Xcode: Go to file > duplicate.

Then name your duplicated xib something like "editProfile" This will give a duplicate of your first xib that you can adjust as necessary